# Magento Shipping returning “Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.” international orders

Tags: magento, ups

I am using magento 1.7.02 and have recently opened up my store for international orders, but I can’t seem to get any shipping rates returned for them.

I have UPS and USPS configured and working for all US orders. I have allow all countries selected on both shipping methods. But when I enter a UK address for example it returns “no quotes are available”. I also have allow all countries in my general config selected.

I can take international payments fine on virtual products.

Here is what I found in my UPS debug file:

```
[accept_UPS_license_agreement] => yes 
[10_action] => 4 
[13_product] => GNDRES 
[14_origCountry] => US 
[15_origPostal] => 55555 
[origCity] => US City 
[19_destPostal] => 55555 
[22_destCountry] => US 
[23_weight] => 3.9 
[47_rate_chart] => Customer Counter 
[48_container] => 00 
[49_residential] => 01 
[weight_std] => lbs
```

It looks like the dest postal and country are the same as the orig. I’m thinking this is the issue, but don’t know how to fix it. For some reason it doesn't seem to pull the correct destpostal or country.

I have been testing with a UK address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the solution. Silly thing on my part. I just needed to have international shipping options enabled through the admin panel.

Comment: where this option is in admin.

Comment: @ravisoni sorry, I didn't see the notification for this post. Are you asking where the shipping is located in the admin panel?

Comment: @ravisoni It's under system -> configuration -> sales -> shipping methods